# MySQL SELECT -> with maximum accordance

Tags: mysql, select, max

I'm working on a recipe DB where the user is first asked to select ingredients. 
Now given the fact that a select query which returns only recipes with the previous selected ingredients would be boring I wondered if there is a way to get those recipes with maximum accordance to the selected ingredients in sql?

In detail:

```
In PseudoCode:
RecipeTable -> Scrambled Eggs(eggs, salt, pepper, milk)
               Fried Eggs(eggs, salt, pepper)

the user enters: eggs, salt and milk

the DB returns: Scrambled Eggs(Accordance: 3), Fried Eggs(Accordance: 2)
```

Comment: You could use MySQL full text search to find the most relevant matches (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or, depending on how your ingredients are structured, group by recipe and order by the number of ingredient-words matched.

Answer (score 1):

ok got it
thanks to your tip to using group by @jspcal

Here's the code

```
SELECT recipes.recipe_name AS Recipe, COUNT(*) AS Accordance
FROM dbo.recipes
INNER JOIN dbo.steps ON steps._recipe_id = recipes._recipe_id
WHERE dbo.steps.ingr_id = (SELECT dbo.ingredients._ingr_id FROM dbo.ingredients 
                           WHERE ingr_name = 'Salt')
OR dbo.steps.ingr_id = (SELECT dbo.ingredients._ingr_id FROM dbo.ingredients 
                        WHERE ingr_name = 'Chicken')
OR dbo.steps.ingr_id = (SELECT dbo.ingredients._ingr_id FROM dbo.ingredients 
                        WHERE ingr_name = 'Spaghetti')
OR dbo.steps.ingr_id = (SELECT dbo.ingredients._ingr_id FROM dbo.ingredients 
                        WHERE ingr_name = 'Apples')
GROUP BY recipe_name
ORDER BY Accordance DESC;
```